# How to automatically refresh external data in Excel 2011 on OS X?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I have an Excel spreadsheet that is pulling in data from an external CSV. I want it to refresh every time I open it, because eventually it's going to be pulling data in from 20 different files. At the moment it says

> security warning "data connections have been disabled"

And then when I override it, it prompts me to reselect the file in Finder.

It sounds like this is pretty easy in Windows Excel, you pretty much just need to enable a setting in the 'Trust Center'. Only, Excel 2011 has no trust center, and as far as I can tell, no way to actually do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

**Refreshing a data table in your Excel workbook**

If your query table is linked to a data source, you can update the data in your workbook on demand so that it reflects the current state of the data source. On the Ribbon’s Data tab, go to the External Data Sources group and click Refresh button’s triangle to display a pop-up menu, where you can choose from the options.